# How to extract text that has no CSS selector with Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So I'm currently scraping several webpages for the text which then will be placed in lists that I can then organize in data frames through Pandas. I'm currently using the `requests` and `bs4` modules.
One of the text that I need to scrape comes in this form:

```
<li><span class="label-description">STATUS</span><span class="text-description"></span>Ongoing</li>
```

And I need to extract 'Ongoing' but it has no CSS selector I can use to use `soup.select(selector)`.
What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

You can select last element from `.contents` of `<li>` tag:

```
print(soup.find("li").contents[-1])
```

Prints:

```
Ongoing
```

---

Or next text element from `class="text-description"`:

```
print(soup.find(class_="text-description").find_next(text=True))
```

Answer (score 0):

What about selecting by class directly?

```
soup.select(".text-description")
```

Comment: @QHarr you're right, I clarified it since I suspect OP is copying 'CSS selector' from developer tools